# couldn't use DateTimeFromUnixNanoseconds Ingestion mapping transform

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Following [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/mappings#mapping-transformations) I tried to use **DateTimeFromUnixNanoseconds** ingestion mapping transform but got "Requested value 'DateTimeFromUnixNanoseconds' was not found.".

In the document it says "DateTimeFromUnixNanoseconds    Converts number representing unix-time (nanoseconds since 1970-01-01) to UTC datetime string" which is what I want.

Here is my python code

```py
CREATE_MAPPING_COMMAND = """.create table telemetries_raw ingestion json mapping 'telemetrylog_raw_json_mapping_v001c' '[{"column":"dataTimestamp","path":"$.time","datatype":"datetime","transform":"DateTimeFromUnixNanoseconds"},{"column":"eventType","path":"$.eventType","datatype":"string"},{"column":"operationType","path":"$.operationType","datatype":"string"},{"column":"rawdata","path":"$","datatype":"dynamic"}]'"""
print(CREATE_MAPPING_COMMAND)

RESPONSE = KUSTO_CLIENT.execute_mgmt(DATABASE, CREATE_MAPPING_COMMAND)

dataframe_from_result_table(RESPONSE.primary_results[0])
```

It’s an useful features but some how it doesn’t work in my code. I am wondering where I missed

Answer (score 1):

You haven't miss anything - this is a relatively new feature, and not all clusters were updated to have the code to support it. The documentation will be updated to clarify the timeline when the feature becomes available in all clusters.